# Having trouble creating Card class

Tags: java

Im having trouble converting the r[rank] to  String. Eclipse keeps saying it needs to be resolved to an array. Also having trouble with Cards[13*i + j] = new Card(i, j); it just keeps saying cannot be resolved to a variable. Heres my code...

```
public class Card {

    private String suit;
    private String rank;
    private static String[] s = { "hearts", "spades", "diamonds", "clubs" };
    private static String[] r  = { "Ace", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "Jack", "Queen", "King" };

    public Card(int suit, int deck){
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < 13; j++){
               Cards[13*i + j] = new Card(i, j); 
            }
        }
    }

    public Card(String r, String s, String suit){
        for(int rank = 0; rank < r.length(); rank+=1){
            if( rank.equals(r[rank]) ){
                this.rank = r+1;
            }
        }
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String getSuit(){
        return suit;
    }

    public void setSuit(String a, String suit) {
        this.suit = suit;
    }

    public String getRank(){
        return rank;
    }
    public void setRank( String s, String rank){
        this.rank= rank;
    }

    public String toString(){
        return String.valueOf(this.getRank()) + String.valueOf(this.getSuit().charAt(0));
    }

}
```

public class Deck {

```
private Card[] deck;
private int inDeck;
private final int SIZE_OF_DECK = 52; 
private int currentCard;

public Deck(){
    deck = new Card[deck];
}

private void init(){

}

public void shuffle(int num){
    int i,j,k;
    for (k = 0; k < num; k++)
    {
        i = (int) (SIZE_OF_DECK * Math.random()*100);
        j = (int) (SIZE_OF_DECK * Math.random()*100);

        Card tmp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[j];
        deck[j] = tmp;
    }
    currentCard = 0;
}

public Card getCard(){
    if (currentCard<SIZE_OF_DECK)
    {
        return deck[currentCard++];
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.print("out of cards error");
        return null;
    }
    }

public int totalCards(){
    return SIZE_OF_DECK ;}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You never initialize your card array... try something along the lines of this before you create each individual object with your loops.

```
Card[] cards = new Card[52];
```

Comment: yeah I'm confused on how to that

Comment: Just make your cards[] a global variable native to the class and you should be fine.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Agreed but he said he needed help with `Cards[13*i + j] = new Card(i, j)` and this would be gearing him towards a fix.

Comment: i also have this program that it goes with and will be tested by my professors tester class.

Comment: i posted it up top. Thank you guys i really do appreciate the help though.